# Perform a global/iterative search in mb_ereg_match

Tags: php, regex

I actually try to reimplement some functionality of a component to provide proper utf-8 support. Is it possible to perform a global (iterative) match (g modifier, which in preg_match it is set by default)?

```
$pattern = 'du\@de\.com';
$whitespacedDude = ' du \@ de\. com  ';
$globalDude = 'a global du@de.com';
$dude       = 'du@de.com';

var_dump(preg_match("/$pattern/", $globalDude, $matches));
var_dump(preg_match("/$whitespacedDude/x", $dude, $matches));

var_dump(mb_ereg_match("$pattern", $globalDude));
var_dump(mb_ereg_match("$whitespacedDude", $dude, 'x'));
```

Gives:

```
true
true
false // this one should be true
true
```

Actually im doing a workaround via `mb_ereg_search` to simulate the global matching. Is there another/better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mb_ereg_match` tests for matches from the beginning only. You need to change your pattern and allow any characters upfront:

```
var_dump(mb_ereg_match(".*$pattern", $globalDude));
```